# In Modular Codeigniter, how can/should one module's controller call another module's function?

Tags: php, codeigniter, module, codeigniter-2, hmvc

I am using CodeIgniter with the HMVC extension by wiredesignz.

My web app deals primarily with text articles. I have a module called `articles`. The model of the articles module, `articles_model`, contain functions that make database changes to the articles. For instance, the following will update the article:

```
$this->articles_model->update_article();
```

There is another module for the user dashboard. Users will sometimes make updates to the articles from within their dashboard. The request is made from the dashboard controller, as this action is executed from views within the dashboard module.

In this situation, how should I let the dashboard controller communicate with the articles model? The couple of options I've come across so far is:

1. Make an `update_article()` function in the articles controller. All it does is call the `articles_model` function of the same name. Have the dashboard controller call the articles controller function `update_article()`. This would be done because I have read that in modular design, the controllers should be the point of communication between different modules ([source](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2010/02/22/scaling-web-applications-with-hmvc/)). I've also come across other opinions that say controllers should never talk to each other. Hence my confusion.
2. I could also duplicate the `update_article()` function in the `dashboard_model`. This way the dashboard controller will only have to call its own model, within its own module. My gut tells me this is not the way to go, as the `update_article()` function is called not only by the dashboard controller, but also quite a few others. This would result in a lot of duplicate code.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The setup you describe seems a little confusing, but `DRY` definitely applies here. Duplicate code due to design constraints is a serious design smell.

Comment: What the setup essentially boils down to is 2 modules, each representing an entity in the system (articles, and the user dashboard). How do I let them communicate?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the model `articles` from module `articles` from another module `Dashboard`.

Just load the model in the constructor function of the module (ex. `Dashboard`) you want the model to be available which should look like this.

```
function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();

  ...

  // this is case sensitive, 1st part is the module, 2nd part is the class name
  $this->load->model('articles/Articles');
}
```

Then anywhere in your controller (ex. `Dashboard`), you can call `$this->articles_model->update_article();`.

Comment: This is what I have been doing so far just to make things work. I'm wondering if this adheres to proper practices for HMVC design.

Comment: Yes, this does adhere to HVMC design. As models are nested in their own modules, you need to access different modules.